# How to evaluate line width in real life?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Sorry if it's too basic, I have some work that where made in Illustrator using the line tool, so it's made of lines with a stroke of 3pt .

Then, I have to print it on large size (vinyl decal) , and I am trying to make sure the line would appear the way I want it .

When I scale my work (by cmd+drag) the lines appears smaller and the work looks bad.

How can I get the result according to what I see in illustrator ? 
(**So the relation between lines distance and their width will look as it looks on my screen**)

Answer (score 3):

On the **Transform Panel** (Window > Transform) *before scaling*, Choose the `Show Options` item from the Panel menu....

[image]

Then tick the **Scale Strokes & Effects** option.

[image]

This can also be accessed by clicking the `Shape:` item on the **Control Bar**

[image]

And it is also located in **Preferences > General**

[image]

---

Ticking this option, in any of these locations, will scale the weights of strokes along with other artwork. Without it ticked, when you scale, the strokes will remain at 3pts.